# MIPS funtions i have some questions for funtions in mips

Tags: mips

I need to use MIPS for a homework but given the time i cant sit and learn all of it so i have some questions that i need to ask in order to understand how it works.
So if i have more arguments for my function than $a registers how can i pass them?
If my function have values that are declared in it how do i do on the stack or at the start of the program?
Are the values that are declared in the start of the program act as global or i cant use or change them in my functions?

I tried reading some slides from some courses but i only get more confused
same as videos.

Comment: 1) Using the stack or some of the other registers. 2) That's up to you. 3) Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer can you please show me with a small example how to pass the arguments to a stack and how to get them in my function?

Comment: Well no need for the example i found a way to do it thank you for the help have a good day.